# How to custom commerce order access?

Tags: commerce

I have a requirement like this: there are some sale men will be assigned some orders to them, these orders are owned by the customers, I want the sale man only can view, edit and update the order assigned to them, they can't view, edit and update the orders assigned to other sale men.

What I have done is add a user reference field to commerce order to record the sale man, but I don't know how to check this access permission, or which function to hook.

Hope someone can point me how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello waveer I think the way to achieve this is something like you have to check before loading the page that the global $user is related to these orders or not.

Comment: Yes, I agree, so I add the user reference field to the order entity, but don't know how to check it or which function to hook

Comment: you have to check the orders related to particular user for that may be you have to use a little bit of php.

Comment: I know it need to code something, I mean which hook function to use.

Comment: I don't think so you can use any hook because here you have to do the trick in some tpl file.

Comment: ok, I understand what you mean, do it in tpl is a solution, hope can find better one.Thank you, harsh!